# How to get rid consecutive characters?

Tags: regex, string, text, sed

I have a text file with the string `a aa aaa aaaa`. I want to reduce this into `a a a a`. However, using `sed -i 's/aa/a/g' filename` results in `a a aa aa`. How would I make all consecutive characters consolidate into a single character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search for `a` followed by [any number](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of `a`s. The search pattern for that is `aa*`:

```
$ echo "a aa aaa aaaa" | sed 's/aa*/a/g'
a a a a
```

A more complicated regex, using [group capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), can be used to match any number of [any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html):

```
$ echo "a aa aaa aaaa bbbb cc" | sed 's/\(.\)\1*/\1/g'
a a a a b c
```